# Removing from a list holding object pointers

Tags: c++, list, object, pointers

I am holding some objects in the list, such as this one:

```
list<CWorm*> wormList;
```

I put the worms on this list, in their constructor:

```
CWorm::CWorm(list<CWorm*>& list, [...]) { 
    list.push_back(this);
```

In the main loop, I perform some events for them, with this:

```
for(itt = wormList.begin(); itt != wormList.end(); itt++) {
    if( (*itt) != NULL ) (*itt)->someEventBlabla();
}
```

Here goes my question:
How do I remove them from a list effectively. When they die, I tried to "erase" them from the list (in the main loop, after checking variables) but it was giving errors of not referenceable iterator.
And when I try to "remove" them from a list (in objects, in the event performed by the main loop) there's then an arror in this line:

```
if( (*itt) != NULL ) (*itt)->someEventBlabla();
```

I've tried to remove them like this:

```
wormList.remove(this)
```

from an object event, with wormList declared as extern.
How do I remove them, leaving blank space for next object??

Comment: Please show to code you tried to use to remove the items so people can tell you how to correct it.

Comment: This design is outrageously terrible. Pointers have no notion of ownership, and even your own code has no way of knowing what the lifetime of those `CWorm` objects is. This is rightly so, as an object should not be concerned with who owns it. But the upshot is simply not to use naked pointers at all.

Comment: I've tried to remove them like this:

    wormList.remove(this)

from an object event, with wormList declared as extern.
To answer this comment: "This design is outrageously terrible. ..." I know. I'm just doing some c++ project, and it's my first time doing something "bigger" :)

Comment: Why not just have a `std::list<CWorm>`? Always think "single responsibility": every component of your design should have one responsibility. The object does its thing, and the container manages the object ownership. Then it's always clear what's going on. Your design mixes things up by making the object meddle with its own ownership, which is unmaintainable and incomprehensible.

Comment: How do I insert them on the list, then? Change their variables etc?

Comment: if worms register themselves during construction they must deregister themselves as well during destruction. this design applies only if the worms die themselves. if the worms get killed from externally there shall be god with ownership creating and killing the worms without the worms even knowing anything about their ownership. and god uses smart pointers.

Comment: @KerrekSB would you please explain to me, how would I do everything that I need, with such design? I don't really understand what does "ownership" mean in this case, etc. I'm beginner in using classes etc.

Comment: @DawidSausSiembab: It's a really bad idea to make an object "register itself". How would you distinguish `{ Foo x; }` and `new Foo;`? The object really shouldn't care who owns it. That's not its responsibility.

Comment: @KerrekSB When I make a list of <CWorm> I can only push one of them onto it. When I try to do 2 worms at the beginning (with "for" loop) there's an assertion when I try to call worm's function (in main loop, where I do it for every worm on a list) :/ Dunno how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably you should work with some kind of smart pointers here. But generally you want to do something like this

```
    using namespace std;
    wormList.erase(remove_if( wormList.begin(), wormList.end(), bind1st(equal_to<CWorm*>(), NULL) ), wormList.end() );
```